# Python: Can't fix IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: indentation

I've messed around with this code in python as much as possible and still can't seem to get it to work

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from time import sleep
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup (23, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    if ( GPIO.input (23) == False ):
        os.system('mpg321 Sioux Goal Horn2.mp3 &')
    sleep (0.1);
```

Every thing I've done to change it, I always get the same message.

```
~ $ chmod +x ButtonBasedGoalSound.py
~ $ sudo python ButtonBasedGoalSound.py
File "ButtonBasedGoalSound.py" line 9
  os.system(''mpg321 Sioux Goal Horn2.mp3 &')
   ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I'd appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have mixed tabs and spaces on that line. Indent with spaces only! Otherwise you will experience great pain.